# Sampled softmax loss eval code works but function call results in ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I am implementing the skip-gram model in a federated learning setup. I get the inputs and label in the following way:

```
train_inputs_embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variables.weights, batch['target_id'])  
train_labels = tf.reshape(batch['context_id'], [-1, 1])
```

When I define the loss as follows

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=variables.nce_weights,
                                                 biases=variables.bias,
                                                 inputs=train_inputs_embed,
                                                 labels=train_labels,
                                                 num_sampled=5,
                                                 num_true=1,
                                                 num_classes=vocab_size))
```

I get the following error

```
 ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'sampled_softmax_loss/concat_4' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [?,1], [?,?,5], [].
```

But, the following code (taken from eval section of sampled_softmax_loss function) works for the **same inputs and labels** !!

```
logits = tf.matmul(train_inputs_embed, tf.transpose(variables.nce_weights))
logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, variables.bias)
labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(train_labels, vocab_size)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels_one_hot, logits=logits))
```

How to fix resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping the train_inputs_embed resolved the error

```
train_inputs_embed = tf.reshape(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(variables.weights, batch['target_id']), [-1, embedding_size])
```